# graph colouring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The graph G has been obtained from the complete graph Kn by replacing each edge $e = uv$ by a 2-edge path $ux_ev$, where each $x_e$ is a new vertex. Find chromatic index of the new graph?

can anyone explain what happens to the chromatic index because in some cases it increases by one and some it stays the same

Comment: Doesn't the chromatic index *decrease* by one for $n=3$?

Answer (score 1):

The chromatic index $\chi'(G)$ is always either the maximum degree $\Delta(G)$, or else $\Delta(G)+1$.

Often it is hard to determine which it is, but for bipartite graphs - such as the one in this question - we always have $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G)$.